# latexdiff highlighted changes are in a different font, how to fix?

Tags: fonts, latexdiff

When I used latexdiff to create a latex file highlighting the differences between my two documents, the new document it produced not only highlights the changes, but changes the font of the highlighted changes. How can I change my latex file so that the font is consistent with the non-highlighted areas?

Answer (score 1):

You should see a line at the top of your new latex file that looks like this:
`\providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{{\protect\color{blue}#1\sf}}`

Simply remove the `\sf` and your fonts should be consistent.